# Jquery move table rows to top

Tags: jquery, tablerow

First off, I stored all my trs with a function, and then I selected part of the trs with this, opening them:

```
// tr = all my stored trs
tr.find("input[value='Selecteren']").click();
// This .click() function changes the input value to "Aanvragen"
```

Now I want to move all the clicked tr's to the top of my table body.

```
//$("#village_troup_list tbody")
```

Getting all the tds is quite simple:

```
tr.find("input[value='Aanvragen']").closest('tr').each(function() {
 //Move every tr
})
```

But how do I move them?

Html structure:

http://jsfiddle.net/4PFf8/1/

Comment: Can you show your HTML structure? jQuery does not include a `move` function. You'll need to use `clone()`, `appendTo()` and `remove()` in some order (depending upon your mark up).

Comment: `$("table").find("tbody").find("tr:first").insertBefore("trs to move")` try this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 $("#village_troup_list tbody").prepend(tr.find("input[value='Aanvragen']").closest('tr'));
```

This works because every tr is viewed as a single tr, and not as a number of trs. So it moves them instead of cloning :)

Comment: thanks this worked. can do this with animation?

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `.prependTo` to move elements to the top of the table. Here is a fiddle illustrating:
http://jsfiddle.net/5uc9H/

Answer (score 1):

Statically move up:

```
onclick="$(this).parents('tr:first').insertBefore($(this).parents('tr:first').prev())"
```

Statically move down:

```
onclick="$(this).parents('tr:first').insertAfter($(this).parents('tr:first').next())"
```